# Python stacks! Specifically stack.push(stack.pop))

Tags: python, stack

I'm having some trouble understanding what stack.push(stack.pop()) does in this code

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push('1')
stack.push('2')
stack.push('3')
x = stack.pop()
y = stack.pop()
z = stack.pop()
stack.push(y)
stack.push(y)
stack.push('2')
while not stack.is_empty():
    print(stack.pop(), end='')
```

I understand that there should be 3 items on the stack, but I don't know what they are and how they will print at the end? And help as to how I can figure this out would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementingaStackinPython.html

Answer (score 2):

`Stack` is an object that functions kind of like a bunch of plates. When you `push`, you are adding a plate to the top of the stack, and when you `pop` you remove one from the top. You wouldn't want to retrieve a plate from the bottom, that is both expensive and unnecessary.

In this case, `stack.push(stack.pop())` does nothing. It will `pop` the item off the top of the stack and `push` it to the top again. In your `while` loop, you `pop` items off of the stack until it has no more items. `pop` returns the item you have removed, so that's how it gets printed

Examples:

```
# declare empty stack
stack = Stack()

# Now the stack has one item in it, a string called "hello"
stack.push("hello")

# x is now a string "hello", and we have removed it from
# the stack. stack is now empty
x = stack.pop()

# stack now has x in it
stack.push(x)

# we add a string "world" to the top of the stack
stack.push("world")

# x is now the value of the top of the stack, "world"
# The stack also only has "hello" in it, since "world" was
# removed
x = stack.pop()
```

Comment: @hotpockets, note also that this means if you push 1, 2 and then 3 and then you pop three times you'll get 3, 2, 1 (that's in reverse order) and now the stack is empty. This is known as a LIFO structure (last-in, first-out)